# CSS: How could I deactivate kerning for my font?

Tags: css

How could I deactivate kerning for my font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS controls kerning with the letter-spacing attribute. Try setting it to 0 to return the font to it's normal kerning.

```
p { letter-spacing: 0; }
```

Comment: CSS **not** "controls kerning", but if using non-zero letter-spacing the "_human kerning perception_" is lost. Example: enhance kerning with `letter-spacing:-0.1em` and lost with `letter-spacing:0.5em`.

Comment: This answer should be deprecated. See below for a better answer.

Answer (score 14):

See the *kerning concept* at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

Kerning is not controlled by letter-spacing, and there are no `font-kerning` for CSS1 or CSS2. The new specification, CSS3, has not been approved as a standard (W3C Recommendation), but there are a property proposed for `font-kerning`, see 2012 draft,

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-kerning-prop

Only specific fonts, like [OpenFonts, have this property](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/features_ko.htm#kern).

Even with **no** kerning control, the use of a non-zero letter-spacing can change the "*human kerning perception*", producing a "deactivate kerning" effect. Example: enhance kerning with `letter-spacing:-0.1em` and lost with `letter-spacing:0.5em`.

With CSS1 `letter-spacing` property you can *lost* or *enhance* **kerning perception**, and into a "letter-spaced text" you can *simulate kerning*:

```
<div style="font-size:20pt;background-color:#bcd">

  VAST   <small>(normal)</small> 
  <br/>

  <span style="letter-spacing:-0.1em">VAST</span>  
  <small>(enhance perception)</small>
  <br/>

  <span style="letter-spacing:0.5em">VAST</span> 
  <small>(lost perception)</small>
  <br/>

  <!-- SIMULATE KERNING AT SPACED TEXT -->
  <div style="letter-spacing:6pt">
     SIMULATE: <span style="letter-spacing:4pt">VA</span>ST TEXT
  </div>

</div>
```

See the [above example here](http://jsfiddle.net/32EQy/1/).

Comment: This answer is the only correct one. `letter-spacing` does not influence kerning, but the *relative* distances between the characters (*after* kerning has been applied).

Comment: But the disadvantage of this technique (the only I could find so far) is that it interferes with the general spacing of a text so that if you have i.g. wide set capitals and you use „kerning“ for some letter pairs it does not „add“ a kerning (subtract) to the pair but set a complete new spacing to it which is not the same. So you would have to recalculate every kerning pair depending on a particular spacing of text zone. A real font kerning does not do this. It adds (subtracts) space to a pair independent of general rhythm.

Comment: Hi @Garavani,  [this *kerning illusion*](http://jsfiddle.net/32EQy/1/) is only for very specific "illusionist effects" (eg. at covers and outdoors). The real *kerning* need better typographic tools (ex. better typesetting in EPUB), and I think that is evolving with the [replacement of old technologies by CSS3-page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345708/287948). It is a big ecossystem of [open standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format) and need  lot of time to be stable and useful... someday perhaps you see webpages using kerning. Check the use of "HTML to PDF" to the nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Use [letter-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp) property

```
<style>
.kern
{
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}
.nokern
{
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}
</style>
<div id="div1" class="kern">
    test test test test
</div>
<div id="div2" class="nokern">
    test test test test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly possible, but you could try to look at the letter-spacing property.

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed`, this disables kerning at least on my browser.

That is to say, `"VA".width == "V".width + "A".width`.

`letter-spacing` does not disable kerning, "VA" is still shorter than "V" + "A".

So, try `text-rendering`. Though it gets a worse text rendering, it does disable kerning.