# Increased kerning on website text

Tags: html, css

We're developing a site for a client right now and my boss (designer only) is once again making me increase letter-spacing on the text so that it looks 'prettier'.  I am of the firm belief that this often causes eye-strain and hinders readability in body copy, but being the boss, she is of course always 'right' until I can provide her with examples showing why she's wrong (generally pretty easy).  In this case, however, I can't find any articles talking about eye-strain and kerning, so I figured I'd ask what you guys think about the issue of increased letter-spacing in web text.

Take a look at http://sparktoignite.com/allograft/process.php and tell me how you feel about the body copy.  We're using font-embedding, so you'll only see the proper font in FF, Safari, and Chrome.  Let me know what you guys think about the readability and eye-strain caused by the font.  My boss currently thinks it's 100% perfect (she wanted the kerning increased further, but I talked her down luckily).

Comment: you're a developer, not a designer. Why are you arguing with a designer about 'the pretty'? You wouldn't appreciate it if she told you which sort algorithm to use. If you're that concerned, suggest that she allow alternate style sheets that are more accessible.

Comment: @dnagirl It is quite possible that Bradley Herman is skilled in multiple disciplines.

Comment: @jessegavin: you may be correct, and my apologies if this is so.  I was more responding to the derogatory tone.

Comment: Yeah it is pretty derogatory. If I was his boss and found this question on SO I would be pissed.

Comment: Sorry, I was being jokingly derogatory. We have a love/hate relationship. I studied comp engineering, she studied design. While I'm mostly just a programmer, I often design as wekk (print & web). The reason I fight the 'designer' a lot is that designers often do not take usability into mind and other issues (like accessibility, SEO, standards). Their concern is always aesthetic only, while I try to push usability. In my op, on the web, design enhances content.  The purpose is to present information, then make it look nice. She doesnt agree. To her, as long as it looks pretty it's fine.

Comment: See the same subject question/answers at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1425703/287948

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally follow the unwritten rule that it's ok to play with kerning on headings, but it should be avoided for body copy. In your particular case, I agree that it's harder to read in general, but I do really like how it makes the compounds (SCCO<sub>2</sub>) and abbreviations (FDA) look. Maybe this is what your boss likes about it?

Either way, I think you're right to fight it. A possible compromise could be to add it only on abbreviations and compounds, though that might look a bit jarring if there's a significant difference. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with the unwritten rule... Headings I think it is fine on, but overall, body copy should be left alone.  We keep getting closer and closer to having words look like "t h i s" and I believe it really hinders readability.  I wish there was a study somewhere to back up my feelings.