# Creating mixed-height justified headlines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typography

I have a design that has a *lot* of three-line mixed-height headlines. Probably the easiest way to explain the look is with an example:

[image: Example]

(For the purpose of this, ignore the fact that the last line has two words.)

Everything's fully-justified, but the font-size and kerning change depending on the length of the word.

Is there any way of doing this with either JavaScript or CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through a boatload of libraries for this project, including:

- [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)

  - Couldn't get it to work so that different lines are different sizes (I.e., justified, but not mixed-height).
- [BigText.js](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/)

  - Couldn't get it to work at all.
- [Stretch](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/stretch)

  - I forget the issue with this, but it didn't work for my purposes.
- Winner: **[SlabText](https://github.com/freqDec/slabText/)**

  - This is what I ended up using, and it works fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for share all this links. Perhaps [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) might help too.

Comment: @Arkana I ended up using Lettering.js to break the text into `span`s. Hugely useful script, though doesn't really have much to do with sizing/justifying text.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Adjusting Kerning in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848715/adjusting-kerning-in-css) for the CSS part and have you take a look at http://kerningjs.com/ ?