# Is there any way to remove the in-font space before (or after) [sans-serif] text?

Tags: css

See the example code:

```css
span {
  font-size: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}
.sans-serif { font-family: sans-serif; }
.serif { font-family: serif; }
```

```html
<span class="sans-serif">Done</span>
<br>
<span class="serif">Done</span>
```

I'm assuming the extra space is "built-in", but is there a way to remove it somehow?

I'm trying to left-align some huge page titles with the much-smaller subtitles underneath.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mna56yf9/6/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Can't you understand you need to post the code in the question and not link JSFiddle? Don't you have the basic sense about it? Yes I am rude, because in spite of the editor having given you an advice, you did a work-around. Seriously, you will never be a good developer.

Comment: What you're trying to do is adjust the kerning of the font. This has been asked about before on StackOverflow plenty of times. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848715/adjusting-kerning-in-css) is the most appropriate duplicate I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has no correct way, because, it is the font that displays that way. Consider the below example:

```css
span {
  font-size: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 8px 0px;
}
.sans-serif { font-family: sans-serif; }
.serif      { font-family: serif; }
.serif2     { font-family: Times; }
```

```html
<span class="sans-serif">Done</span>
<br>
<span class="serif">Done</span>
<br>
<span class="serif2">Done</span>
```

[image]

The above image has different layout if it is a serif in my computer. So, it is a trial and error basis and you have to make sure what you are doing is fine in all computers and browsers. The `Times` font fits perfectly and the `serif` font has some space. This is why I said it is a *trial and error* method.

The only **hacky** solution is to use a negative margin for the content, based on the font and you **cannot** generalize it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a minus margin-left. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/mna56yf9/5/ But if you're planning on having a background color, you might have to apply it to a wrapping div.

```
span{
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: The text sticks out of the background a bit, doesn't it?

Comment: Play with the number. 20px was just for demo.